# Link Loaded from other file via jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I opened a link which looks exactly like this: http://localhost/anysite/#data_aa

Then, jquery performs the following:

```
$('a[href^="data_"]').click(function(){
    //code to be executed and at end,
    $("anyDIV").load('anyfile.php?parameter=anyvalue');
});
```

This selects all the links where the `href` attribute starts with "data_" to load data from PHP file.

Data and links are loaded successfully but the loaded links do not work which exactly looks as same I mentioned in beginning like this `http://localhost/anysite/#data_ss`...

Hope, You understood my problem and will be able to help me......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

```
$('a[href^="data_"]').live('click',function() {
    //code to be executed and at end,
    $("anyDIV").load('anyfile.php?parameter=anyvalue');
});
```

The `click` bind happens at page load, so any content dynamically added afterwards wont be included in that bind, the `live` method facilitates this.

Comment: Hey, it is working.... Thanks man, You saved my Many hours... Really Very much thankful.